# Referring input Long Text Variable in multiple screens on Flows

Tags: community, visual-workflow, business-logic

I have created a Long Text Variable (say Case Numbers) component on Screen 1 in salesforce Flows. Here my requirement is, to pass the data entered in 'Case Numbers' to second screen Long Text Variable (Say Confirm Case Numbers). Below are the approaches i tried but didn't gives me a complete solution:

1. Created Case Numbers and Confirm Case Numbers variables and passed Case Numbers value as a default value to Confirm Case Numbers field. Problem here is, data is coming to 'Confirm Case Numbers' only once. If I go back to Screen 1 and change Case Numbers field value, it is not carrying to Confirm Case Numbers.
2. Assignment operator approach is not working as there is no option to assign the value to Long Text Area variables.
3. If i try to use same variable name in both fields, duplicate api name error is trhowing which is expected.

Any workaround solution would be helpful on this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set the **default** value of your **second** long text variable to the one from the **first** long text variable and they are placed in different screens,

you probably could not see the changes in Screen2 when you go back from Screen2 to Screen1 and edited the **first value** in Screen1 and go to Screen2;

Because by default, the **Advanced setting** is set to make sure the value is preserved the same as when the user last visited the screen.

You can change these setting by clicking on the component and navigating to the **Advanced** section. (please refer to the image below)

you can go to your second Long Text Variable, click on it, under the Advanced section, check this option:

> **Refresh inputs to incorporate changes elsewhere in the flow**

[image]

Then it will automatically, render the value, when the value changed from its previous screen.